# Last-Modified in http header

Tags: asp-classic, http-headers

I request a website header, however, there is not Last-Modified info in this http header. I wanna creat a site map and get each file's date on the server. Don't understand why there is not this info for some websites. How did some softwares, such as Xenu, get the file's date.

Comment: Is this any website, or one that you control? what httpd is the website you talk about running?

Comment: *“HTTP/1.1 servers* should *send Last-Modified whenever feasible.”* – a “should” is no “must”. Besides, for dynamic content some sites may not keep track of the last modification date or bother determining and outputting it.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Are you creating a site map for third-party sites? And, what's your programming lang/tool (or are you running telnet requests in a command line prompt?)

Comment: I just wanna know how can get the page's Last-Modified date for any third party site?

Comment: I am trying to write some codes in classic asp in order to get a site map for any web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Johannes Rössel points in his comment to your question, the Last-Modified header is not compulsory. If it is there, you can read it just like any other HTTP header (the exact method depends on your exact code so we can't say more until there's code). If it isn't there, you can't read it. It's as simple as that. You can't fetch information about remote resources unless the remote server provides such piece of info. That's valid for HTTP and most other network protocols.